# Usage of DoEvents() in VB 6.0

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am having one case and need your advice whether to use DoEvents() / Any Other / Nothing to use.

I have developed an application in VB 6.0 before 5-6 Years and is working fine.

Now From some time as Data is increased (MS Access), It gives some unexpected result.

I am using DbName.Execute "...Query to Update Tables..." and then after this line I had Used DoEvents(), to let DbName.Execute Query to be completed first and then go ahead with the rest of the code.

So Is it the right use of DoEvents(), as I had monitored that in some Advanced CPU, the problems occurs due to non executing the Query / Query is Running Still the rest of the code is executed

I actually want to Stop executing further code, once the Query Executed Completely, Then I want to execute further code

Please Guide !

Comment: Are you coding in VB6 or VBA within Access?

Comment: The answer to the question "Should I ever use `DoEvents() in VB 6.0" is of course **no**, other than perhaps for debugging purposes. Can you edit your post to show some code so that we can provide more specific suggestions?

Comment: In Access, on the other hand, DoEvents is actually useful in a number of cases, but it doesn't do what is described in the question here.

Answer (score 5):

The DAO and ADO `.Execute` methods both operate synchronously by default.  In other words, the next line of code does not execute until the query finishes processing.  You do not need to use `DoEvents` or While Loops or anything else.

You can force the `Execute` method to run asynchronously by setting the option flag [`dbRunAsync` in DAO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243015%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or [`adAsyncExecute` in ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If either of these flags is set (you don't specify whether you are using DAO or ADO) then simply deleting them from the method call will force your code to wait until the query is done before going to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ensure your Execute operation has been completed and written to disk by operating it within a transaction.  Here's what Access 2003 Execute Method help topic says about transactions:

*For best performance in a Microsoft Jet workspace, especially in a multiuser environment, nest the Execute method inside a transaction. Use the BeginTrans method on the current Workspace object, then use the Execute method, and complete the transaction by using the CommitTrans method on the Workspace. This saves changes on disk and frees any locks placed while the query is running.*

See if an approach likes this eliminates your unexpected result.  If not, describe the unexpected result you're hoping to avoid.

```
    Dim objWorkspace As DAO.Workspace
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSql As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set objWorkspace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set db = CurrentDb
    objWorkspace.BeginTrans

    strSql = "UPDATE YourTable SET some_field = Null;"
    db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    '* additional db.Execute operations if desired *'
    objWorkspace.CommitTrans

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set db = Nothing
    Set objWorkspace = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    objWorkspace.Rollback
    GoTo ExitHere
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the same idea. I would do the following as you asked "whether or not to use DoEvents()

```
Dim i as long
i = 0

Do
  i = i + 1
   DoEvents() ' Is this what you were asking?
Loop Until i = 5000
```